# S2-quickStart not generating Login/LogOut controller and views also

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am using `grails 2.5.2 version`, I am new to Grails , tried to use spring security core, I have created app and configured `compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:2.0.0"` in `buildConfig.groovy` file
 and did `grails compile` then

```
s2-quickstart org.test.secureapp SecUser SecRole
```

after executing this command only domains are created, I searched in net for solutions, In stackOverFlow also previously asked this question, in the answer block provided some links which are not working now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The controller and views are in the plugin. It's expected that users will want to customize the domain classes (typically just the user class though) but it's less likely to need to override the controller functionality or views, so they're part of the plugin itself (see [here](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/tree/2.x/grails-app/controllers/grails/plugin/springsecurity) and [here](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/tree/2.x/grails-app/views/login)).

They can be customized though, just like any artifact class or GSP in a plugin - just create a class or GSP with the same name in the same relative location in your app (controllers in grails-app/controllers/grails/plugin/springsecurity and GSPs in grails-app/views/login) and yours will be used instead.